# Change rotation of Metapost pens dynamically while drawing

Tags: metapost

What I'd be looking for is something like this:

```
pickup pencircle scaled 50 yscaled .5;
draw z1{rotated 40} .. {rotated 60}z3;
```

What this would mean is that the pen starts out rotated 40 degrees, but ends up rotated 60 at the end of the stroke.

I'm trying to use Metapost to generate letter forms for a font I'm designing, but unfortunately it can be awkward to describe certain shapes without having to resort to just using bezier curbs.

Comment: This is what the `penpos` and `penstroke` macros do.

Comment: @Thruston is there any documentation those? They don't appear to be mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `penpos` and `penstroke` macros which Metapost inherits from Metafont.  Unfortunately they are not documented in the usual manual, but they work as described in [the Metafont Book](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfbook?lang=en).  Here's an example:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
z1 = origin;
z2 = 200 right rotated 10;

penpos1(8,40);
penpos2(10,60);

drawoptions(withcolor .7[blue, white]);
penstroke z1e..z2e;

endfig;
end.
```

[image]

The idea is that for each point you define (z1, z2, etc) you also define `penpos1`, `penpos2`, etc, where the parameters are the breadth and rotation of the pen nib.  You then call the `penstroke` macro with the path you want.  But note that you have to write not, `z1..z2` but `z1e..z2e`.  The `e` suffix is translated into `l` and `r` in the right order by some macro magic in `penstroke`.

You can read the source definition in `plain.mp`.

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to use ``penstroke`` with other pens though? using ``pickup pencircle`` beforehand doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @KevinKeith No.  If you look at the macro definition in `plain.mp` you will see that it's actually doing a `fill` and not using a pen at all.  The effective nib you get is razor thin with variable breadth and angle.  Again, I recommend that you read the relevant chapter in the Metafont Book.